# processmodel in Machine.config for performance

Tags: .net, iis, web-config, config, processmodel

We have scenario as one web-two app. Inside of app, there are two elements. If we look at the front-end, at the app side we have configuration fail and in the same side, the usage of cpu is 20%. My machine config is below.

```
<processModel autoConfig="false" maxWorkerThreads="100" maxIoThreads="100" minWorkerThreads="20" minIoThreads="20" />
```

Maxconnection is 500 in web.config.

How can I fix the configuration fail in app side?

[image: The view of My app from outside]

[image: The view of My web from outside]

Firstly The second picture(web) calls the first picture(app).when using mobile phone response time is not under the load as 0.0 ms or 1 ms around 1.000 session but around 30.000 session as 40 sc - 60 sc according to above picture you can see the result after 30.000 session. I think there is not any fail in application coding and but I think there is a fail in iis configuration fail. The first picture(App side) opens around 190 connection when it is under the load. Second picture opens around 380 connections when it is under the load.

Comment: What is the problem? You can edit the configuration in many ways, but before that you must first identify what happened.

Comment: Firstly The second picture(web) calls the first picture(app).when using mobile phone response time is not under the load as 0.0 ms or 1 ms around 1.000 session but around 30.000 session as 40 sc - 60 sc according to above picture you can see the  result after 30.000 session. I think there is not any fail in application coding and but  I think there is a fail in iis configuration fail. The first picture(App side) opens around 190 connection when it is under the load. Second picture opens around 380 connections  when it is under the load.

Comment: make that part of the question please. Nobody checks comments.